# How to embed a html file into an air package by using Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have an Air Application which uses mx:HTML to show a html Page.

This html page is located in my bin-debug and as long as i start my application out of FB it works fine.

In Project -> Properties -> Flex Build Packaging -> Package Content the test.html is selected

When I build the project by Project-> Export Release Build the HTML file is not included in the Air Package and so cannot be shown.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bin-debug folder will not be compiled into your release build application.

Place the html page somewhere in an assets folder like so:

YourProjectRoot > src > assets > html > test.html

Cheers

Comment: ok sounds good, how do i have to format the url now ? <mx:SWFLoader x="0" y="0" source="balsamiq_simple.swf" width="100%" height="100%"/> nun the swf is in /src/assets . Is the Folder name assets a reserved name ? So that the Compiler knows to include it into the package

Comment: No you can call the folder any name you want, whatever is under your root folder will be exported to your release build when it is not embedded with embed metadata tags. The format would then be something as follows <mx:SWFLoader x="0" y="0" source="assets/balsamiq_simple.swf" width="100%" height="100%"/> when your swf is at YourProjectRoot > src > assets > swf> balsamic_simple.swf

Comment: ok very nice, works now the way i want... very hard to get an interactive pdf running in an air application seamlessly